# What is the evolutionary advantage to a lifespan limit?

Tags: genetics, evolution, intelligence, lifespan

How/Why

Do Koi have a lifespan of hundreds of years?
Do humans have a lifespan of decades?
Do dogs have such a short lifespan?

Within these questions I pose further questions.  How does size relate to lifespan. Elephants?

If dogs were to evolve independent of humans (at this point) would they rule the world?

Comment: This question is far too broad, because you are asking too many questions. Please limit yourself to one focused question per post.

Comment: An interesting question and @Wesley has answered it quite nicely. Apart from this, I would like to direct you to a neat article published by [Yaneer Bar-Yam in PRL](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.238103) last year on when does natural selection favour limited lifespans. A detailed explanation was given in [Gizmodo website](http://io9.gizmodo.com/are-limited-lifespans-an-evolutionary-adaptation-1710634703) last year.